# Can you stream games you bought in PS store through PS Now?

Tags: ps4, ps-now

I've recently got myself a psNow subscription to be able to play some ps4 games, even though I don't own one.

But I was wondering, if I decide to buy a game that is not currently available to stream via the psnow service, can I still play it through the service ? Or do I need a ps4 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PS Now you can play only games available through service, which are called "PS Now Game Collection":

> Install the PS Now App. You’ll have access to the full PS Now game collection

[source](https://www.playstation.com/en-us/explore/playstation-now/ps-now-on-pc/)

All available games could be searched [here](https://www.playstation.com/en-us/explore/playstation-now/games/)